# Call JDialog from JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm trying to build an application, in which allows calling `JDialog` from `JDialog`. I've tried it, but at the time of the call dialog B of A, B dialog appears and then immediately disappears. Is there a solution to these problems?

My code :

I have a class A which extends `javax.swing.JDialog`. Then there is a label that has the action to call dialog from class `PadAndZoom` as below:

```
 private void lblSuratRekomendasiMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    try {
        PadAndZoom app = new PadAndZoom();

        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(PadAndZoom.class.getResource("/tampilan/background5.jpg"));

        app.tes(img);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RincianBukuBesar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

then I have one more class to be invoked by the method `lblSuratRekomendasiMouseClicked` (`java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt`) of class A

```
package dispertasih;

import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.*;  
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;  
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;  
import javax.swing.event.*;  


public class PadAndZoom implements ChangeListener {  
    BufferedImage image;  
    PanPanelX label;  


    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {  
        int value = ((JSlider) e.getSource()).getValue();
        double scale = value / 200.0;
        BufferedImage scaled = getScaledImage(scale);
        label.setImage(scaled);
    }  


    public BufferedImage getScaledImage(double scale) {  
        int w = (int)(scale*image.getWidth());  
        int h = (int)(scale*image.getHeight());  
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, image.getType());  
        Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();  
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,  
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);  
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale, scale);  
        g2.drawRenderedImage(image, at);  
        g2.dispose();  
        return bi;  
    }  

    public PanPanelX getContent() {  
       // createAnImage();  
        label = new PanPanelX(image);  
        //label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);  
        return label;  
    }  

    public void createAnImage(BufferedImage imgbuf) {  
        int w = 500;  
        int h = 500;  
        int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB; // many options  

            image = imgbuf;


    }  

    public JSlider getControl() {  
        JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 50, 200, 50);  
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(50);  
        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(10);  
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);  
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);  
        slider.addChangeListener(this);  
        return slider;          
    }  

    public void tes(BufferedImage img) {  
        PadAndZoom app = new PadAndZoom();  
        JDialog f = new JDialog();  
        JButton b = new JButton();
          try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) { }


             app.createAnImage(img);


        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);  
        f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(app.getContent()));  

        //f.getContentPane().add(new JButton("tessss"));
        f.getContentPane().add(app.getControl(), "Last");  
        f.setSize(400, 400);  
        f.setLocation(200,200);  
        f.setVisible(true);  
    }  
}  
class PanPanelX extends JPanel {

public int x, y;
public int width = 800, height = 800;
BufferedImage img;
public final static RenderingHints textRenderHints = new      RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
public final static RenderingHints imageRenderHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
public final static RenderingHints renderHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
static int startX, startY;
 public void setImage(BufferedImage img) {
        this.img = img;
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
public PanPanelX(BufferedImage img) {
    x = 20;
    y = 20;
    this.img = img;

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            super.mousePressed(me);
            startX = me.getX();
            startY = me.getY();
        }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
            super.mouseDragged(me);

            if (me.getX() < startX) {//moving image to right
                x -= 2;
            } else if (me.getX() > startX) {//moving image to left
                x += 2;
            }

            if (me.getY() < startY) {//moving image up
                y -= 2;
            } else if (me.getY() > startY) {//moving image to down
                y += 2;
            }
            repaint();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {
    super.paintComponent(grphcs);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) grphcs;

    //turn on some nice effects
    applyRenderHints(g2d);

    g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, null);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(width, height);
}

public static void applyRenderHints(Graphics2D g2d) {
    g2d.setRenderingHints(textRenderHints);
    g2d.setRenderingHints(imageRenderHints);
    g2d.setRenderingHints(renderHints);
}
}
```

thanks u ..

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect us to know what your problem is if you don't show your code. This is not a Swing problem per se, but rather a bug in your program problem, and the solution is for you to fix the bugs in code you've not shown us. If you need our help, you will want to isolate the error and then show us the relevant code. Note that we don't want to see *all* of your code, and in particular don't want to see code not related to your problem. Best to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Is it an overridden dialog or just `OptionPane`?

Comment: thank you for responding to my question, I've added code.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Can you post some text explaining it for us? In particular, where do you call your 2nd dialog, etc ... Assume we understand nothing about your code and your problem.

Comment: I had to change it, sorry I beginner in java, I am just a person who wants to learn

Comment: Some further tips though:  1) Add @HovercraftFullOfEels (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* them of a new comment. 2)  It is generally not necessary, and bad practice, to extend components like dialog or panel unless changing functionality.  3) `PanPanelX` **does** change functionality, specifically through custom painting, but the same could be achieve by displaying the image in a `JLabel` with an `EmptyBorder`. 4) When custom painting, it is important to call the `super` method, and since `JPanel` is an `ImageObserver`, the image draw method should use `this` instead of `null`.

Comment: Oh, and 5) Creating a new instance of `PadAndZoom` in the `PadAndZoom.tes(..)` method seems like a bug to me. 6) Note that a `JLabel` makes for a poor `JButton`.  A button with an `ActionListener` will respond to mouse ***or keyboard*** actions.

Comment: In addition to @AndrewThompson's 6) point: it will also allow use of AbstractActions and will allow expected behavior if the button is disabled.